# How to overlay AEM cq dialog for component?

Tags: aem

Using Adobe Experience Manager (AEM), I'm trying to overlay the cq/searchpromote/components/search component.

I have copy/pasted the folder and my search.jsp is working as it should with new functionality.

My dialog won't work. It still reads from the original default component. The naming and path are the same so I believe it should work.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the component is still displaying the original dialog rather than the overlay version?

Comment: post the code?  Did you update the component group in _cq_editConfig.xml?